# socket, smtp and web exceptions

Tags: c#, email

I've been getting an error sending e-mail messages from my application. I checked with my hosting company and got the correct mail server setting but I'm still getting error messages. Any suggestions? Stack trace and code below.

```
    [SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 68.178.232.62:25]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +251
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) +279

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout) +6136880
   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +314
   System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback) +21
   System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout) +322
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +146
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint) +222
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection() +50
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1496

[SmtpException: Failure sending mail.]
   System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message) +1829
   Lostpass.EmailUser(User user) +713
   Lostpass.uxUserInfoSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +446
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +112
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +36
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +5563

    <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="Network" from="support@<domain>.com">
        <network host="relay-hosting.secureserver.net" port="25" defaultCredentials="true"/>
    </smtp>
</mailSettings>

    void EmailUser(User user)
{
    user.ChangePasswordID = Guid.NewGuid();
    user.Save();
    MailMessage email = new MailMessage();
    email.To.Add(new MailAddress(uxEmail.Text));
    email.IsBodyHtml = true;
    email.From = new MailAddress(Settings.LostPasswordEmailFrom);
    email.Subject = Settings.LostPasswordSubject;
    //email.Subject = "your new password";
    email.Body = EmailTemplateService.HtmlMessageBody(EmailTemplates.MembershipPasswordRecovery, new { Body = Settings.LostPasswordText, BeginRequired = "", EndRequired = "", UserName = user.Name, GUID = user.ChangePasswordID.ToString() });
    //email.Body = "your new password is: password";
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    //try
    //{
    client.Send(email);
//}
    //catch
    //{ Exception ex; }

    uxSuccessPH.Visible = true;
    uxQuestionPanel.Visible = false;
    uxUserInfoPanel.Visible = false;
    uxUserNameLabelSuccess.Text = uxEmail.Text;
}
```

Comment: Have you seen this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11621373/using-smtpclient-and-getting-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it?

Comment: check to see if you have proxy enabled. this might be because of proxy. if there is no proxy make sure you choose the right smtp port and enable the ssl in your code.

Comment: Thanks, Jaroslaw. My machine claims not to have telnet. My ISP is having me send a Trace Route to them. I also asked them to make sure that relays from remote machines aren't disabled.

Comment: @Bravo11: Would the relay issue I'm describing above be similar to the proxy issue you mention? I don't have much knowledge or experience about dealing with proxies. I am also double-checking with my ISP regarding the correct SMTP port.

Comment: ya if you are behind the proxy this is a frequent issue you would get but you know lots of error messages are similar but the actual problem is different so it's hard to tell the actual reason unless i am debugging in person. hope you understand that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that `defaultCredentials` is correct? I suspect that's going to send your Windows login credentials, which probably isn't what your ISP needs. I think you need to set the [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials.aspx) property on your `SmtpClient` instance. Something like:

```
// set your SMTP server login credentials
System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = 
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.Credentials = credentials;
```

Comment: Thank you, Jim. Since I'm still getting the "refused" error, I will first try to resolve the Socket and Web exceptions noted above, then add more later regarding the SMTP issue.

Comment: Here are some further discoveries I've made: I can send e-mail messages running the project on the ISP's remote server but not on my local machine (the error message comes from running the project locally). Strange, because in my experience, most projects favor the local machine over a remote machine. I turned off both Windows Firewall and Kaspersky firewall but those actions didn't work. Any further suggestions based on this new information?

Comment: @muybn: Some service providers block port 25. I know that mind did (might still), so I couldn't do SMTP from my house. You might try using telnet to connect to the SMTP server. If you can't even get a connect, then you know that it's most likely not your program that's causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I have tried Telnet a few times for other suggestions but found an article which states it doesn't come activated in Win7 by default and how to install it: Programs and Features/Turn Windows features on or off/Telnet Client (for those who run into the same roadblock). Is there another port that would be better to use?

I used the following with the Command Prompt (ran as Administrator) and all failed. Does any of them look like the right format?

telnet relay-hosting.secureserver.net
telnet 68.178.232.62:25
telnet 68.178.232.62

Comment: @muybn: The point is to see if you can connect to *any* SMTP server on port 25 from the machine that's having trouble. If you don't even get a "hello" or a prompt for a password, then it's highly likely that your service provider (the one providing the Internet connectivity to your location) is blocking port 25. Or you might just contact their tech support and ask.